# Unable to read two different files in succession

Tags: c++

I am writing a program which can take 3 commands, command1 , command2  and bye. The first two commands are supposed to read a file and do something with the data in those files.

The problem right now is that.. it wont work on 2 different files in succession. For example..

```
command1 testing.txt
... THIS WORKS ...
command1 testingagain.txt
wrong command! try again!
```

I want the commands to work each and every-time I input it with any file name. I am not sure how I can change the structure of my code to make that happen.

```
while (getline(cin, str1)){

        if (str1 == "bye")
        {
            return 0;

        } else {
            s1.str (str1);
            s1 >> command;
            s1 >> filename;
            ifs.open(filename.c_str()); 

            if (ifs.fail()) {                                                       
                cerr << "ERROR: Failed to open file " << filename << endl;   
                ifs.clear();   

            } else { 

                if (str1 == "command1 " + filename) {
                    command1(filename);

                } else if (str1 == "command2 " + filename) {
                    command2(filename);                                                              

                }   else {
                    cout << "Wrong command! try again!" << endl;

                } 
            }
            ifs.close();
        }
    }
    return 0;
```

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/

Comment: std::string overloads `operator==()`

Comment: Only if `#include <string>`. So... @sparta93 do you have a `#include <string>` line in your code?

Comment: How otherwise use `std::string` at all?

Comment: I've seen strings usable, and always assumed they were included as a side effect of some other include file, but then have seen "some stuff" for string not work - until I include <string>.

Comment: If `string` is included as a side effect then your inclusion will be just ignored because header contains include guard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`s1.str (str1);` doesn't work as you expect. You should create new `istringstream` object every time:

```
istringstream s1(str);
s1 >> command;
s1 >> filename;
```

or add `clear()` after `str()`:

```
s1.str(str);
s1.clear();
s1 >> command;
s1 >> filename;
```